# Modelling the creation of an Actor in a use case diagram

Tags: modeling, use-case

If you believe that a use case flow of events creates an actor, how would you model that?

I have a use case that creates a windows service, which (in my mind) is another system with its own set of use cases and actors.

At the moment it is not obvious from the use case diagram that an actor gets created as part of the flow of events.

Aidan.

Answer (score 0):

Use case diagrams do not display a sequence of actions. There is no time dimension. As a result, it makes no sense to create or delete an actor.

Comment: Yes a use case diagram does not imply time or sequence. A use case flow of events description does imply time and explains sequence. 
Since it is expected that all actors mentioned in a use case are shown in the use case diagram, and I believe my use case creates an artifact that is modelled else where as an system ie an actor, I wanted to know if I should be concerned that the created actor wasn't appearing in my use case diagram. I take your reply that since the diagram has no time line I should not be worried.

Thanks